# Are there any limitations of using the Threading library for small async tasks in a Django environment?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-multithreading

I know that there are better, robust alternatives such as Celery, but for lightweight tasks, are there any disadvantages or gotchas of using the Threading library in a Django production environment?

Environment : Django 1.5+, Python 2.7, uWSGI/Gunicorn web-server, centOS 6.5

Comment: One thing you want to be aware of is mixing processes and threads.  If you spawn threads and then spawn processes, you could have deadlocks in your spawned processes.

Comment: Yes, ill keep that in mind